# Virtual Host not recognized

Tags: apache, virtualhost, vhosts

currently I'm trying to set a VHost but somehow it is not working.
I've disabled the vhosts in my machine and I have just one. The page does not load. If I access localhost I get 403 Forbidden

My vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@myvhost.test
    ServerName myvhost.test

    DocumentRoot /folder/to/app
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /folder/to/app>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and if I run

```
apache2ctl -S
```

I get

```
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
    default server myvhost.test (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/myvhost:1)
    port 80 namevhost myvhost.test (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/myvhost:1)
Syntax OK
```

What am I missing here?

Thank you

Comment: Is there any `NameVirtualHost *:80` in the config?

Comment: In apache2/ports.conf

Comment: that means `VirtualHost` with `*:80` is the name-based virtual host. In this case the `Host` header must match to the `ServerName`/`ServerAlias`. Define `ServerAlias localhost`

Comment: Multiple `Options` all must be with +/- (add or remove mark). For the CGI must be defined the proper `SetHandler` eg `SetHandler cgi-script`.